# MoviePy error: FFMPEG permission error

Tags: python, django, apache, ffmpeg, moviepy

I am using Moviepy through a Django application on Ubuntu 14.04 system. It is giving me permissions error when it tries to write video file. Following are details of error :

MoviePy error: FFMPEG encountered the following error while writing file test1TEMP_MPY_wvf_snd.mp3:

test1TEMP_MPY_wvf_snd.mp3: Permission denied

It seems it has not correct permissions on directory where it is trying to write temporary files.

I have set the 777 on /tmp directory but no luck.
Please help me fix this issue.

Thanks

Comment: Just want to update on this issue. We can pass full path of temp video in moviepy's Write Video file method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After spending lots of time and trying lots of things, I have finally solved this issue. 
We can pass full path of temp video along with it's name, then it will create temp video at given path. Make sure you have write permissions on directory which you are going to set for temp video.

Answer (score 5):

There exist a

```
temp_audiofile
```

parameter in the write_videofile function that by defaults creates a temporary directory to store the mp3 file of the video. Moviepy attempts to create the directory in a random location that most likely doesn't have write and execute permission for non-root users, hence the permission denied complaints. Simply

```
chmod -R 777 <directory of your choice(preferably tmp)>
```

in the terminal, then pass the absolute path of that directory accompanied with a made up file name to temp_audiofile parameter like this

```
final_clips.write_videofile(abs_path, temp_audiofile=/tmp/random_name.mp3)
```

That should fix the permission denied issue.